# How to prove that a grammar is LL(k) for k>1

Tags: grammar, ll-grammar

I have this exercise which gives me a grammar and asks to prove that it is not an `LL(1)`. All good with that part, though afterwards it asks me if that grammar can be an `LL(k)(for k>1)` or not. What procedure do I follow to determine that?

Comment: Can you provide any more details? As is, all I can recommend is learning about general proof techniques (construction, induction, contradiction, etc)

Comment: the grammar is:

P -> P;S|S     
S->kEy|xSy|aPb|k   
E->ES|w   

where x,y,w,a,b,k are terminal symbols.
I want to prove that this is an LL(k) grammar for k>1

Answer (score 1):

For a given `k` and a non-left-recursive grammar, all you have to do is to build the `LA(k)` table (by algorithms readily available everywhere). If there is no ambiguity, the grammar is `LL(k)`, and the language is too.

Knowing if there exists a `k` for which a given language is `LL(k)` is undecidable. You'd have to try one value of `k` after the other until you succeed, or the universe runs out.